# css - change an image frequently with less server requests

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, class

I have a  in html. Its content is described in css.
With different functions the classname of the div is changed to imageholder1,2 etc.

```
.imageholder1 {      content: url('image1.png')}
.imageholder2 {      content: url('image2.png')}
```

But I think this causes multiple server requests , each time the classname is changed.

Is there a way to reduce the server requests to the image file.
I would like a way to store the image into a variable and then point it from css code. Is it possible?

I also tried to use a css image sprite but I need to need a more flexible way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to this will be 'No', because you need to get those images **somehow** so you'll always need to make a request per image. You could do it on `$(document).ready()` but you'll still have to do it at some point

Answer (score 3):

If you put all your images in a hidden (display none) div, they'll load all at once. The browser should cache them, so then each time it changes, it pulls from the client system.

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <img src="image1.jpg">
  <img src="image2.jpg">
  <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: But how can I use this with css. I need to show image1 at a time, and then image2 like that.

Comment: If you know in advance all the images that will be used, then you stick this anywhere in the HTML document. Then when the CSS changes, the browser already has the image. It's how I did the rollovers at [www.tecbrat.com](http://www.tecbrat.com)

Comment: So does that mean if an image is loaded once , it is reused from the cache, even though the css points out to source file url?

Comment: Yes. The browser should "know" that it already has that file, and therefore won't request it from the server again.

Answer (score 1):

Preload the images and it will cache the images and only request each image once (it will also allow for smoother transitions between the images because subsequent images will already be downloaded). This will limit your http requests to one request per image (the minimum you can achieve without sprite sheets).

Here is a really nice jQuery solution (that doesn't add hidden elements to the DOM) but really any preloading scheme should work:

```
$.preloadImages = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}

$.preloadImages("hoverimage1.jpg","hoverimage2.jpg");
```

*[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/image-preloader/)*

Answer (score 1):

According to me, if we load multiple images on a page it is going to have multiple requests.
Instead of this simply use a sprite combining all the images.
This will cause to fetch a single image from server.
Then define css properties for [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) for classes such that they will have different position values of the sprite used causing to show required image.

```
.imageholder1 {
  background: url(/path/to/sprite.png) -60px -120px no-repeat;
}

.imageholder2 {
  background: url(/path/to/sprite.png) -20px -120px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the approach, but I tried css image sprite and it is not flexible - I need this images to be resized later by code. In that cases the thing gets complicated. I was looking for an easier way :-)